# Discord.py get user with Name#0001

Tags: python, discord.py

How do I get the user/member object in discord.py with only the Name#Discriminator? I searched now for a few hours and didn't find anything. I know how to get the object using the id, but is there a way to convert Name#Discriminator to the id?

The user may not be in the Server.

Comment: Are the users you're trying to find also in the server(s) your bot is in?

Comment: Maybe, I want to get it for a command with which you can add users to a list of banned users and i want to find out if they are with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bot can only get a User instance, that it isn't in a server with, from a unique ID.

You can use both [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get) and [`get_all_members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/neo-docs/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_all#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_all_members) to get a Member using your input though:

```py
member = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_members(), name='name', discriminator='discriminator')
# discriminator should not contain #
```

P.S afaik utils.get takes any kwarg that could be an attribute for a class

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it if you aren't sure they're in the server. If you are, you can search through the servers' members, but otherwise, it wouldn't make sense. Usernames/Discriminators change all the time, while IDs remain unique, so it would become a huge headache trying to implement that. Try doing what you want by ID, or searching the server.